# Android интерфейс съезжает

Tags: java, android, xml

Кнопка съезжает вверх, а верхние тексты исчезают, код и результат на скринах
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ConstraintLayout - это layout, где каждый элемент зависит от другого, то есть "элемент относительно другого элемента". Обратите внимание на те кружочки, которые представлены на макете в режиме дизайна. Как минимум, необходимо, чтобы один горизонтальный и один вертикальный кружок был притянут к элементу. Чтобы это сделать, удерживайте курсор мыши на данном кружке и проведите стрелку к такому же кружку на другом элементе, тогда должно всё работать.

Также не забывайте обращать внимание на ошибки и предупреждения от idea